# What will be the motion of an electron kept at rest in the vicinity of a magnetic monopole?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

Consider that both an electron and a [magnetic monopole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) are kept at rest close to each other. Will this result any motion of the electron? If yes, please give a derivation of the equation of motion.

Comment: Classical electron and classical monopole? What's the mass of the monopole?

Comment: Also to consider: what if the electron starts oriented with spin in the direction (or anti-direction) of the monopole? It's magnetic dipole moment would mean the two particles necessarily are going to be attracted or repelled. And a similar situation if the magnetic monopole can have an electric dipole moment...

Comment: I'm not sure whether they can have dipole moments despite of being at rest to each other. The hypothetical situation I have tried to present here is that both the electron and the magnetic monopole are free from any external electromagnetic field. There exist only pure monopole fields of an electric and a magnetic charge.

Comment: @Subhra True, but (for example) the electron has intrinsic spin, and spinning charges (electron in a loop for example) generate a magnetic field - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment

Comment: @XerenNarcy If you think on that way then the concept of electrostatic field will become meaningless.

Comment: It's not even clear what the actual field of a magnetic monopole should look like. One can model it with a scalar potential like an electric charge or with a vector potential, but the two cases are not identical if I understand this correctly.

Comment: I wish to look monopole as a classical counterpart of electric charge. Therefore, it should have a scalar potential.

Comment: I think Wolfram has solved the problem for you: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ClassicalElectronInTheFieldOfAMagneticMonopole/

Comment: I saw that link earlier. But I guess it's not on stationary charges. Are you sure?

Comment: @Subhra The way I understand your comments, you are interested in the spin dynamics of the electron. Then it is irrelevant, whether you use a magnetic monopole or a solenoid to create the magnetic field (as the precession of the spin will only depend on the local magnetic field). Otherwise the Wolfram result seems to be the answer. Furthermore, it is relevant whether your magnetic monopole has an electrical dipole moment (an electron carries electric charge and a magnetic dipole moment!).

Comment: @SebastianRiese No, not at all. I am only interested in the behavior of an electric charge placed in the vicinity of a magnetic charge / monopole under the condition that there is no relative motion between them. Wolfram dealt with the case when there is an initial relative motion between them. The case is easy when you consider a relative motion between them, because the force laws will then come into play. While in the case I am interested in, the velocity is ZERO.

Comment: 1. I don't see why Wolfram's result would not be valid for $v=0$ 2. This is just a homework-like question asking for the solution of an equation of motion.

Comment: @ACuriousMind With v = 0, how can it follow a spiral path?

Comment: I meant the *solution of the equation of motion* Wolfram gives, not the simulation. Click on "more" to see the derivation, and you see that they quickly arrive at $\partial_t r^2 = v^2$. There are one or two steps in the derivation that follows that where you have to be careful about dividing by zero, but they essentially solved it for you.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, look at the starting point given in the last sentence of the 2nd para : v is not considered to be zero and if it is considered, F will become zero.

Comment: And now for something completely different, the almost real thing: http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v10/n1/full/nphys2816.html

Comment: The paper doesn't consider the case v=0. For non zero v the problem is well explained by Griffiths (problem 5.43)

Comment: "Kept at rest" is a *terrible* formulation when referring to initial conditions.

Comment: This is an exercise in Griffiths as well.